# How to display an array of object in ejs with conditions

Tags: mysql, node.js, if-statement, foreach, ejs

i'm doing a web app to manage my money with node Js.

Here is what it's look like :
[image]

I've done almost everything, but I still have one part to do, which is to display my last 30 transactions.
I can't display my transactions as I want. It is necessary that if the date of the current transaction is different from the transaction just before then it displays the date and the transaction otherwise just the transaction. I block at the condition level if the date is different

At first I tried to display the first transaction with the date and then use (for) or (for in) to display the others with the condition but i can't use the i variable in my array of objects.

like this :

`<%= transaction30[0].DateT%>`

`<%= transaction30[0].Name%>`

`<%= transaction30[0].Montant%>`

`<% for var i in transactions30 %> or <% for var i=1; i<= transactions30.length;i++%> {`

`<% if(transactions30[i].DateT != transactions30[i-1].DateT) %>`

then display date and infos

`<% }else{ %>`

juste display infos

`<% } %>`

Then I read somewhere that you shouldn't use (for) for arrays of objects. So I tried a forEach.
Here is my code :

```html
                    <h1>
                        <%= transactions30[0].DateT %>
                    </h1>


                    <% let status=transactions30[0].DateT %>
                        <% transactions30.forEach(function(item){ %>
                            <% console.log(item.DateT," et ",status) %>
                                    <% if(item.DateT!=status) {%>
                                        <h1>
                                            <%= item.DateT %>
                                        </h1>
                                        <div class=" activite">
                                <div class="transaction-image"></div>
                                <div class="transaction-info-container">
                                    <p class="transaction-nom">
                                        <%= item.Nom %>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="transaction-categorie">
                                        <%= item.Categorie %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <p class="transaction-montant">
                                    <%= item.Montant %>
                                </p>
                </div>
                <% status=item.DateT %>
                    <% }else{ %>
                        <div class="activite">
                            <div class="transaction-image"></div>
                            <div class="transaction-info-container">
                                <p class="transaction-nom">
                                    <%= item.Nom %>
                                </p>
                                <p class="transaction-categorie">
                                    <%= item.Categorie %>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="transaction-montant">
                                <%= item.Montant %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <% } %>
                            <% }); %>
```

The 'prevdate' variable is updating well, but it always display date of all transactions. The (if) condition work but only for the first transaction because i dont get the date of the first transaction two times ( i display the first date at start, out of the forEach condition)

Here is the array for better comprehension : [array named transactions30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNRYX.png)

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Hello Alexys, I don't get your question. you want to update prevdate each time? And please share code instead of pictures

Comment: Hello @Aimsat, I want to dipslay all my transactions grouped by date with date write in title. As you can see on the bottom left part of my sketch (first image)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the solution. Instead of (if date != previsousdate) i had to do
if(date < previousdate || date > previousdate)
and now it's work

```html
<h1>
                        <%= transactions30[0].DateT %>
                    </h1>


                    <% let status=transactions30[0].DateT %>
                        <% transactions30.forEach(function(item){ %>
                            <% console.log(item.DateT," et ",status) %>
                                    <% if(item.DateT>status || item.DateT < status) {%>
                                        <h1>
                                            <%= item.DateT %>
                                        </h1>
                                        <div class=" activite">
                                <div class="transaction-image"></div>
                                <div class="transaction-info-container">
                                    <p class="transaction-nom">
                                        <%= item.Nom %>
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="transaction-categorie">
                                        <%= item.Categorie %>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <p class="transaction-montant">
                                    <%= item.Montant %>
                                </p>
                </div>
                <% status=item.DateT %>
                    <% }else{ %>
                        <div class="activite">
                            <div class="transaction-image"></div>
                            <div class="transaction-info-container">
                                <p class="transaction-nom">
                                    <%= item.Nom %>
                                </p>
                                <p class="transaction-categorie">
                                    <%= item.Categorie %>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="transaction-montant">
                                <%= item.Montant %>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <% } %>
                            <% }); %>
```